# Putting .txt file directly into array java

Tags: java, arrays, file, import

I am writing a hangman code, and for school I have to use a list containing all Dutch 10 letter words, which are about 80.000 words. I would like to put them in an array, but I don't have the time to do

```
String[] wordList;
wordList[1] = AAGJESAPPEL (first word)
wordList[2] = AAIBAARHEID (second word)
```

etc etc. Is there a way to import these words from the .txt file they are in, and put them directly into an array? The words are all on separate lines, and i would like for each word to be a new additon to the array. I know there are other posts on this topic, but those are too difficult for me to understand, please help me :)

Comment: I'm not sure why it's `-1` but you initialized `x` and `y` as `0`.

Comment: print values of x and y and check if it is crossing bounds.

Comment: the printing really helped :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the first cycle you enter to

```
 if (direction.equals("up") && upcounter < 6) {
       y = y - 1;
       upcounter++;
  }
```

As y=0 in the beginning, after than block y=-1.

I suggest you to debug your code to understand what is happening

Comment: I got it figured out, I'm not so good with left and right, so I put for go to left x++; and go to the right x= x-1;, thats what caused the array to get out of bounds, thanks for all the help :D